# How to adapt Makefile for make tests target?

Tags: c++, makefile

My folder structure looks like this:

```
src
--main.cpp
tests
--src
----main_test.cpp
Makefile
```

I want to make a target like `make main_test`, in order to be able to run test program as `./main_test`.

Initially I had a Makefile, which I haven't modified for a long time. So I started modify its content, in order to create new `main_test` target.

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 -Iinclude
LDFLAGS =

EXE = main
SRCDIR = src
BINDIR = bin
OBJDIR = tests/bin

OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(BINDIR)/%.o,$(wildcard 
$(SRCDIR)/*.cpp))

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(BINDIR) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXE) $(LDFLAGS)

$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -MMD -o $@ $<

include $(wildcard $(BINDIR)/*.d)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

main_test: $(OBJDIR) tests/bin/main_test.o
    g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 tests/bin/main_test.o -o tests/main_test

tests/bin/main_test.o: $(OBJDIR) tests/src/main_test.cpp
    g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 tests/src/main_test.cpp -o tests/bin/main_test.o

clean_tests:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BINDIR) $(EXE)

.PHONY: clean all
```

Unfortunately, something went wrong:

```
make main_test
mkdir -p tests/bin
g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 tests/src/main_test.cpp -o tests/bin/main_test.o
g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 tests/bin/main_test.o -o tests/main_test
tests/bin/main_test.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x1f0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
tests/bin/main_test.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
tests/bin/main_test.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
tests/bin/main_test.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
tests/bin/main_test.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
tests/bin/main_test.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
tests/bin/main_test.o:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in tests/bin/main_test.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'main_test' failed
make: *** [main_test] Error 1
```

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the compile rule for `tests/bin/main_test.o` you missed `-c` command line option.

---

Use an [order-only dependency](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) for output directories, e.g.:

```
main_test: tests/bin/main_test.o | $(OBJDIR)
```